# ¿Como darle formato (ordenar) al código en el IDE Itellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

¿Hay alguna opción para organizar el código en el IDE **Itellij IDEA**?

En NetBeans es click derecho-Format.

Comment: prueba con alt + shift+ f

Comment: @RaulCacacho, creo que esta es la respuesta. Si consultas la documentación y publicas una respuesta *(con el enlace de la documentación)*, la comunidad votará a favor. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Pense que iban a cerrar la pregunta por eso solo comente pero 1+ jaja

Answer (score 4):

Si te refieres a identar el código, el atajo (shor-cut) es **Ctrl + Alt + L**.

Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/ide/intellij-idea-format-code-example/) a un post sobre unos truquillos más que te pueden servir.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a la lista de comandos mediante el menú de ayuda abriendo `Help > Keymap Reference`

[image: Ubicación en el menú ayuda]

Allí verás que el que tiene por defecto es <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image: teclas en la referencia oficial]

Afortunadamente son configurables, así que si vas a settings mediante `File > Settings` puedes usar **los mismos comandos que en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)** si eliges el perfil que viene en el dropdown en la pestaña Keymap dentro de la ventana de Settings.

[image: IDEA settings de keymap]

Adicionalmente, para realizar la transición de comandos de un *Keymap* a otro te recomiendo el plugin [Key Promoter x](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9792-key-promoter-x), que te muestra un pop up cada que realizas una acción que tiene un método abreviado por teclado, es decir si por ejemplo vas a `File` y abres `Settings` te aparecerá un pop up con el comando para abrir la configuración si es que existe en tu perfil de *keymap*, que por defecto es <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + L
Aquí puedes encontrar la documentación de Jetbrains y su keymap
https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Para mi lo mejor es que al guardar el archivo se formatee automaticamente.
para eso hay que ir a: file/setting. En setting ir a Actions on Save y activar el checkbox  "Reformat code". Debes tener activado tambien en Setting/editor/java el check "Enable javadoc Formatting".-

Espero que les sirva.
saludos.

Answer (score -1):

En **Netbeans** la para darle un formato al código, presionando las teclas **alt + shift + f**, ayudara a ver de forma ordenada tu código.

Puedes ver más atajos en este [enlace](https://byspel.com/atajos-de-teclado-en-netbeans/)

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912), como podrás ver si lees de nuevo la pregunta es acerca de IDEA, no de Netbeans

Comment: efectivamente, Ese es el comando para agregar a favoritos en IDEA

Comment: @RuslanLópez En vez de botar negativo pon la respuesta correcta para que OP decida

Comment: por favor lee el artículo, creo que te ayudará a entender por qué no es bueno para la comunidad tener respuestas incorrectas, gracias por la sugerencia, ya la he agregado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/227052/342